# Flask index.html not loading on localhost

Tags: python, flask, github, web-applications, repository

I built a flask repository from https://github.com/kdelwat/Onset and followed all of the instructions from the README, but when I cd the 'run.py' and run Flask's development server, I go to the localhost (http://127.0.0.1:5000/) and it loads up nothing, just a blank page. I took a quick look at the index.html file and everything seems to be running okay. Before that incident happened, when I went into the directory there was no template file so I created a "templates" file in the directory and moved the index.html there, but then there was a no-template error. Then I moved the templates file into the 'app' folder and the error was gone, so I run the Flask server again and I am still here.

### Edit while writing

I ran in on an HTML compiler and I think that when I run the index.html the code itself is just the title with nothing else. I am very confused. What am I supposed to put in templates folder? Is there a problem with the injecting? Please help.

Here is the run.py code:

```
from app import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

As requested from Michael Amadi, here is my [directory structure.](https://pastebin.com/ZM0EpWqD)
P.S I am new to Python and coding in general, so maybe I just don't know how to set up a Web-app at all.
init.py:

```
from flask import Flask

app=Flask(__name__)

from app import views
```

views.py:

```
import json
import sys
import os.path as path

from flask import render_template, jsonify, request
from app import app

base_directory = path.dirname(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(path.join(base_directory, 'engine'))
import engine
import metrics

optimisation_functions = {'Maximise': max, 'Minimise': min}
metric_functions = {'weighted phonetic product': metrics.weighted_phonetic_product,
                    'phonetic product': metrics.phonetic_product,
                    'Word Complexity Measure': metrics.word_complexity_measure,
                    'number of syllables': metrics.number_of_syllables,
                    'number of consonant clusters': metrics.number_of_consonant_clusters,
                    'random value': metrics.random_value}


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


def sanitise(string):
    '''Remove all whitespace from a string and lowercase it.'''
    banned_characters = "'.-–—‒ \u02C8"

    return ''.join([c for c in string.strip().lower() if c not in
                    banned_characters])


def format_transcriptions(transcriptions):
    '''Split the raw string of transcriptions into
    the correct tuple rules.'''
    clean_transcriptions = transcriptions.strip().lower()

    if len(clean_transcriptions) == 0:
        return []
    else:
        return [(sanitise(pair.split(':')[0]), sanitise(pair.split(':')[1]))
                for pair in clean_transcriptions.split('\n')]


@app.route('/evolve')
def evolve():
    words = [sanitise(word) for word in request.args['words'].split()]

    try:
        transcriptions = format_transcriptions(request.args['transcriptions'])
    except IndexError:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Transcription seperator must be a colon'})

    try:
        generations = int(request.args['generations'])
    except ValueError:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Generations must be an integer'})

    if request.args['direction'] == 'Reverse':
        reverse = True
    else:
        reverse = False

    optimisation_function = optimisation_functions[request.args['optimisationFunction']]
    metric = metric_functions[request.args['metric']]

    try:
        words, rules = engine.run_engine(words, generations, transcriptions,
                                         reverse, metric, optimisation_function)
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)})

    return jsonify({'rules': rules, 'words': words, 'error': 0})


@app.route('/apply')
def apply():
    '''Evolves the language according to the given rules, specified by:

        words: list [strings]
        rules: list [Rules]
        reverse: if True, apply in reverse order (used when applying rules
                 created by reverse evolution)
    '''
    words = [sanitise(word) for word in request.args['words'].split()]
    rules = json.loads(request.args['rules'])

    if request.args['direction'] == 'Reverse':
        reverse = True
    else:
        reverse = False

    try:
        transcriptions = format_transcriptions(request.args['transcriptions'])
    except IndexError:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Transcription seperator must be a colon'})

    try:
        evolved_words = engine.apply_rules(words, rules, transcriptions,
                                           reverse)
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({'error': str(e)})

    return jsonify({'words': evolved_words, 'error': 0})
```

Comment: Hi @MollyRollyPo A, could you show your project directory (folder) structure and full code of run.py?

Comment: @MichaelAmadi I have added the directory structure on Pastebin. As for the run.py code, that's all there is to it. However, I can show you the init.py and the views.py code in the .app file if you want.

Comment: Okay views.py, do include the index.html as well.

Comment: @MichaelAmadi I have pasted the init.py and the views.py on the post, I was not able to include the index.html because Github renders it as text and it outputs "Onset", so I made another Pastebin with the index.html.

https://pastebin.com/f5NPMgaB

Comment: looking at both index.html and the index view (endpoint), there's nothing going on inside the view and the template isn't receiving any data to display.

Comment: @MichaelAmadi Is there anything in the code that I can resolve to fix the issue of the template not injecting the files?

Comment: No idea @MollyRollyPo A, Except if I try the repository you referred to, 24hrs Maybe. Btw, Do you have npm installed?

Comment: @MichaelAmadi Try the repository and see if it works on your computer. Also I do have npm.

Comment: @MichaelAmadi Did you find anything?